# Need a script that runs on each ID rather than just the last one called

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I've got a task manager of sorts that needs data pulled from a database. Each task also needs to display a modal with its details. Among which is a map with a marker. This is where my problem lies.
The nature of my modals is that each task has its own modal created for it. Thus meaning that the map has to have a different id on each modal.

```
<?php

                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks";

                            $result = $conn->query($sql);

                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                // output data of each row
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                                $id             = $row["id"];       
                                $task_name      = $row["task_name"];
                                $client_id      = $row["client_id"];
                                $priority       = $row["priority"];
                                $description    = $row["description"];
                                $assigned_to    = $row["assigned_to"];
                                $start_date     = $row["start_date"];
                                $due_date       = $row["due_date"];
                                $lat            = "-26.722804"; //this will need to change once i've figured out the $id issue
                                $lng            = "27.088537";

                        ?>

                        <!-- View Modal -->
                        <div id="task-detail-modal-<?php echo $id; ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="full-width-modalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

                                    <div class="modal-body p-t-0">

                                        <div class="p-10 task-detail">

                                            <div class="media m-t-0 m-b-20">
                                                <div class="media-left">
                                                    <a href="#"> <img class="media-object img-circle" alt="64x64" src="assets/images/users/avatar-2.jpg" style="width: 48px; height: 48px;"> </a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="media-body">

                                                    <h4 class="media-heading m-b-5">
                                                        <?php 
                                                            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM clients where id = $client_id");
                                                            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                                                            echo $row['contact'];
                                                            }
                                                        ?>
                                                    </h4>
                                                    <?php 
                                                    $color = getAlert($priority);
                                                    $priority_text = getAlertText($priority);
                                                        echo '<span class="label label-'.$color.'">'.$priority.' - '.$priority_text.'</span>'
                                                    ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <h4 class="font-600 m-b-20"><?php echo $task_name; ?></h4>

                                            <p class="text-muted">
                                                <?php echo $description; ?>
                                            </p>

                                            <ul class="list-inline task-dates m-b-0 m-t-20">
                                                <li>
                                                    <h5 class="font-600 m-b-5">Start Date</h5>
                                                    <p> <?php echo $start_date; ?></small></p>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <h5 class="font-600 m-b-5">Due Date</h5>
                                                    <p> <?php echo $due_date; ?></small></p>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                            <div id="map-<?php echo $id; ?>" style="height: 400px; width: 100%"></div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">Save Changes</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                        </div><!-- /.modal -->
                        <script>
      function initMap() {
        var v_lat = <?php echo $lat ?>;
        var v_lng = <?php echo $lng ?>;
        var v_mapID = 'map-'+<?php echo $id ?>;
        alert(v_mapID);
        var myLatLng = {lat: v_lat, lng: v_lng};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(v_mapID), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map
        });
      }
</script>
                        <?php
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo "0 tasks";
                            }
                        ?>
```

Instead of going through each id, the script seems to only recognize the last id that was called. Meaning only that id's modal's map will work. How do I get it to run the script for each ID rather than just the last one?

Comment: Where do you put the script part? Because that has to be part of the loop. Could you post the complete code? instead of the script part in a separate block.

Comment: I had it as part of the loop before but that didn't seem to fix the issue. I've reverted to that for now and edited the script above accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix the issue. Now a new map is created in the for loop for each id

```
<script>
    var maps = []
</script>
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $id             = $row["id"];
        $task_name      = $row["task_name"];
        $client_id      = $row["client_id"];
        $priority       = $row["priority"];
        $description    = $row["description"];
        $assigned_to    = $row["assigned_to"];
        $start_date     = $row["start_date"];
        $due_date       = $row["due_date"];
        $lat            = "-26.722804"; //this will need to change once i've figured out the $id issue
        $lng            = "27.088537";

        ?>

        <!-- View Modal -->
        <div id="task-detail-modal-<?php echo $id; ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="full-width-modalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

                    <div class="modal-body p-t-0">

                        <div class="p-10 task-detail">

                            <div class="media m-t-0 m-b-20">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <a href="#"> <img class="media-object img-circle" alt="64x64" src="assets/images/users/avatar-2.jpg" style="width: 48px; height: 48px;"> </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">

                                    <h4 class="media-heading m-b-5">
                                        <?php
                                        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM clients where id = $client_id");
                                        while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                                            echo $row['contact'];
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </h4>
                                    <?php
                                    $color = getAlert($priority);
                                    $priority_text = getAlertText($priority);
                                    echo '<span class="label label-'.$color.'">'.$priority.' - '.$priority_text.'</span>'
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <h4 class="font-600 m-b-20"><?php echo $task_name; ?></h4>

                            <p class="text-muted">
                                <?php echo $description; ?>
                            </p>

                            <ul class="list-inline task-dates m-b-0 m-t-20">
                                <li>
                                    <h5 class="font-600 m-b-5">Start Date</h5>
                                    <p> <?php echo $start_date; ?></small></p>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <h5 class="font-600 m-b-5">Due Date</h5>
                                    <p> <?php echo $due_date; ?></small></p>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <div id="map-<?php echo $id; ?>" style="height: 400px; width: 100%"></div>
                            <script>

                                maps.push({
                                    mapContainer: 'map-'+<?php echo $id; ?>,
                                    lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>,
                                    lng: <?php echo $lng; ?>,
                                });

                            </script>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">Save Changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

        <?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 tasks";
}
?>


<script>
    function initMap() {
        for(var i = 0; i < maps.length; i++)
        {
            var myLatLng = {lat: maps[i].lat, lng: maps[i].lng};

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(maps[i].mapContainer), {
                zoom: 16,
                center: myLatLng
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map
            });
        }
    }

    initMap();

</script>
```

Comment: This gives me the same result as before.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (taskboard.php:1485)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Its hard for me to know what is going wrong. without more information. Do you have an online version somewhere?

Comment: Actually that's something unrelated that I've solved. Now it only gives a console error about a cookie or some such. Doesn't seem to be related to the map though.

Comment: Oh, which part do you want? The code? Or do you want to see it function online?

Comment: I have updated the code. Instead of calling new Maps on every loop it now just creates an array with map-ids and the lat/long's. I cant test it because I dont have the data, so give it a spin and let me know!